# How to populate dropdownlist using WCF Rest AngularJs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, wcf-rest

How to populate dropdownlist using WCF Rest Service:

First, this is my code to get service:

*service.js*

```
(function (app) {
app.service("GetCategoryService", function ($http) {
    this.GetCategory = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:51458/ServiceRequest.svc/GetCategory/");
    };
});
})(angular.module('entry'));
```

*Entry.Ctrl*

```js
(function (app) {
    'use strict';
    app.controller('entryCtrl', entryCtrl);
    entryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function entryCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.pageClass = 'page-entry';
        //To Get Category
        $scope.Category = function () {
            var promiseGet = GetCategoryService.GetCategory();
            promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.GetCategory = pl.data },
                  function (errorPl) {
                      console.log('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
                  });
        }
    }
})(angular.module('entry'));
```

This is entry.html

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select ng-model="Category" ng-options="item.ITEM_TEXT for item in Category"></select>
</div>
```

WCF Output JSON like:
`[{"ITEM_TEXT":"INTERNAL APP"},{"ITEM_TEXT":"INTERNAL IT"}]`

I don't know how to passing this to html, what I'm doing like this is not working. please  help. thank

Comment: You forgot injecting the service in the controller...Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: Haven't any error. I know this is missing inject to controller. But I don't know how to do it

Comment: When I add `$scope.Category();` in the entryCtrl.js hv errror like `GetCategoryService is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.Category `

Comment: That was the error I was talking about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have set `ng-model` different from the `array name`, also inject the service into your controller,

```
entryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'GetCategoryService'];
```

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
 
    $scope.Category = [{"ITEM_TEXT":"INTERNAL APP"},{"ITEM_TEXT":"INTERNAL IT"}];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
   <select ng-model="selected"  ng-init="selected = Category[0]" ng-options="item.ITEM_TEXT for item in Category"></select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Stfvns i dont get it

Comment: using structure like in `entryCtrl.js`. When I using like your answer it's not get from my wcf rest service @Sajeetharan

Comment: just change like this,  <select ng-model="selected"  ng-init="selected = Category[0]" ng-options="item.ITEM_TEXT for item in GetCategory "></select>

Comment: yess. Then I edit my entryCtrl.js `entryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'GetCategoryService'];` Then it's work

Comment: Not helpfull. You don't answer to add `entryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'GetCategoryService'];` This is important think to work my code